# Поиск скриншота в текущем изображении дисплея

Tags: java

Есть набор скриншотов(далее подскриншоты), есть необходимость понять, как написать программу на джава, которая сможет брать поочередно каждый подскрнишот с набора и проверять, содержиться ли этот подскриншот на текущем изображении дисплея.
 На данный момент есть лишь одна идея:
 Перевести каждый подскриншот в массив пикселей, и если первый пиксель совпадает с одной из картинок, то проверять далее.

Может есть более рационально решение, возможно, чтобы зайдествовать передачу полноценного подскриншота для его проверки, а не как просто набор пикселей.

Comment: любое изображение на экране состоит из набора пикселей. не понятно, что вы вкладываете в выражение **полноценный подскриншот**.

Comment: Погуглите computer vision и javaCV